# Passing values into nested for loops in django

Tags: python, django

I am getting hung up between tutorials and documentation for backwards relationships. I think my issue is that I'm not passing the right information from my view into the template, but I'm unsure how to address it. I want to be able to pass all of the "lift" values from the LiftSets object to thier specific Session. My for loop for Sessions (or total_workouts) is working, but I cannot get anything to populate the nested for.

```
# views.py
def workout(request):
    total_workouts = Session.objects.all()
    total_sets1 = LiftSet.objects.all()

    context = {
        'total_workouts' : total_workouts,
        'total_sets1' : total_sets1,
    }


    return render(request, 'blog/workout.html', context=context)


# workout.html
    {% for workout in total_workouts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ workout.author }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ workout.date_posted|date:"F d Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="">{{ workout.name }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">
                    test
                    {% for child in total_sets1.session_set.all %}
                        {{ child.lift }}
                    {% endfor %}
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

Foreign key in LiftSet to associate to Session.

```
class Session(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class LiftSet(models.Model):
    lift_options = (
        ('S', 'Squat'),
        ('B', 'Bench'),
        ('O', 'OHP'),
        ('R', 'Row'),
    )
    lift = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=lift_options,
        blank=True,
        default='m',
        help_text='What Lift',
    )
    set = models.IntegerField()
    reps = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    status_options = (
        ('P', 'Planned'),
        ('C', 'Completed'),
        ('F', 'Failed'),
        ('N', 'Not Attempted'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=status_options,
        blank=True,
        default='P',
    )
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  # don't actually want this as CASCADE

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lift
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that since you are already calling out all objects of `LiftSet` model in `total_sets1 = LiftSet.objects.all()` and you're passing that as a context it is no longer necessary to do this in the template:

```
 {% for child in total_sets1.session_set.all %}
     {{ child.lift }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Change that to:

```
{% for child in total_sets1 %}
    {{ child.lift }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also I might change that `views.py` into:

```
def workout(request, *args, **kwargs):
    total_workouts = Session.objects.all()
    total_sets1 = LiftSet.objects.all()

    context = {
        'total_workouts' : total_workouts,
        'total_sets1' : total_sets1,
    }


    return render(request, 'blog/workout.html', context)
```

I hope this helps to solve your problem.

EDIT:

On your `views.py`, if you are using class based views modify your `get` function like this:

```
def get(self, request, sessionName):
        """GET method."""
        id = Session.objects.filter(name = sessionName).first()
        liftset = LiftSet.objects.filter(author= id)
        context = {
            "your_context": your_context 
        }
        return render(request, your_template.html , context)
```

Comment: Thank you. This got the looping working, but it is the entire database of LiftSets vs. the LiftSets associated to the Session in the top loop.

Comment: No error.

It is giving me: Session 1 then Liftset1, Liftset2, Liftset3; Session 2 then Liftset1, Liftset2, Liftset3. As opposed to Session 1 w/its liftsets and session 2 with its liftsets like: Session 1 then Liftset1; Session 2 then liftset 2 & 3.

Comment: I edited my answer to help solve that problem.